# Updating IIS 5.0 to IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, windows-xp, iis-5

I want to update the IIS server from 5.0 to 6.0 or higher.

The condition is that I cant upgrade the server. My machine is Windows XP SP3

Is there any way I can only update the IIS.

Comment: Wait, you're running a *web server* on Windows XP? Don't bother upgrading IIS. Just ditch the machine and give up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [IIS Express 7.5](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) on Windows XP. Note that the *Express* version is a lightweight (yet fully featured) version of IIS meant for development purposes, not production hosting. You shouldn't use Windows XP as a production server anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it on XP Pro 32bit

Check the link here - http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

Answer (score 0):

I have installed IIS 6.0 Manager for my Windows XP SP3 32-bit from this link:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15662

In Control Panel->Administration Tool (I guess its name translated from italian :) now I have two items:

- *Internet Information Services* - the 5.1 version bundled with the OS
- *Internet Information Services (IIS6) Manager* - the installed version from the link above